# как с помощью jQuery свернуть один блок div и сразуже развернуть другой

Tags: html, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста как с помощью jQuery свернуть один блок div и сразуже развернуть другой потом наоборот. Это действие должно происходить по нажатию на ссылку
например

```
<div id="div1"> 
   <a href="#">скрыть div1 и показать div2</a> 
</div>

<div id="div2"> 
   <a href="#">скрыть div2 и показать div1</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что речь про аккордеон, где базовое состояние - все блоки скрыты и может быть больше 2ух блоков, но как задача описана, такие и ответы ...

Comment: отметьте пожалуйста подходящий для Вас ответ решением, чтобы он не висел в открытых. Для этого нажмите на серую галку слева от ответа, галка станет зеленой, что будет означать принятие ответа как решения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#div1').on('click', function(){
  $('#div1').fadeOut(300, function(){
    $('#div2').fadeIn(300);
  });
});

$('#div2').on('click', function(){
  $('#div2').fadeOut(300, function(){
    $('#div1').fadeIn(300);
  });
});
```

```css
#div2{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"> 
   <a href="#">скрыть div1 и показать div2</a> 
</div>

<div id="div2"> 
   <a href="#">скрыть div2 и показать div1</a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**1. Вариант с [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)** -
*отображает или скрывает выбранные элементы*

```js
$('.toggle').on('click', function() {
  $(".toggle").toggle();
});
```

```css
.toggle {
  display: none;
}

.toggle:nth-child(1) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="toggle">
    <a href="#">скрыть div1 и показать div2</a>
  </div>

  <div class="toggle">
    <a href="#">скрыть div2 и показать div1</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**2. Вариант с [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)** - *отображает или скрывает выбранные элементы со скользящим движением (по сути тот же toggle())*

```js
$('.toggle').on('click', function() {
  $(".toggle").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.toggle {
  display: none;
}

.toggle:nth-child(1) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="toggle">
    <a href="#">скрыть div1 и показать div2</a>
  </div>

  <div class="toggle">
    <a href="#">скрыть div2 и показать div1</a>
  </div>
</div>
```